# Get a pandas column name as a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am having a dataframe containing multiple columns and multiple rows. I am trying to find the column which contains the entry `'some_string'`. I managed to this by

```
col = df.columns[df.isin(['some_string']).any()]
```

I would like to have `col` as a string, but instead it is of the following type

```
In [47]:
print(col)

Out[47]:
Index(['col_N'], dtype='object')
```

So how can I get just `'col_N'` returned? I just can't find an answer to that! Tnx

Comment: this is because multiple columns can have `some_string` hence returns a list. If you only need the first column name go for `df.columns[df.isin(['some_string']).any()][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat your output as a list. If you have only one match you can as for

```
print(col[0])
```

If you have one or more and you want to print then all, you can convert it to a list:

```
print(list(col))
```

or you can only pass the values of col to the print:

```
print(*col)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think typecasting will help

```
list_of_columns = list(df.columns)
```